# How can I implement keyring_aws.so plugin over MySQL 8.0.23 community edition installed on AWS EC2 with Amazon Linux 2 Image

Tags: mysql, database, encryption, plugins, open-source

I understand that the Plugin is available for Enterprise MySQL only. However it is also available as a open source under MariaDB. I am trying to implement column level encryption on my MySQL 8.0.23 over AWS EC2. Can someone let me know if this possible, or is there any other open source plugin from Percona which gives the same functionality. Please help with the link to directly download the such plugin if available.

I need to know if there are any other ways of having column level encryption on MySQL Community edition. This need to be implemented from database only not from the application end.

Answer (score 0):

The encryption on the underlying MariaDB, and I assume MySQL is the same way that applies on the table level. InnoDB pages are read from disk and decrypted. This is the lowest level of functional encryption/decryption.

Options with existing encryption are:

- Put your encrypted column in its own table and join to it
- Encrypt the entire table

Comment: Hi Dan
Thank you for taking time to answer the question, but I do understand what you said in the reply. But the question is how do i implement column encryption on MySQL community version. I can do table level encryption or do an encryption at rest for the entire database or tablespace alone.
my requirement is column level encryption on particular table.

Comment: Its not possible unless you write your own storage engine. I don't think you can fake it with a generated column either. There probably is a low overhead in doing an entire table and it isn't as much CPU overhead as you expect.